# Background Video Not Working in Safari

Tags: video, safari, youtube-api, ytplayer

I have used [jquery.mb.YTPlayer](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/wiki) plugin to put background video in my site and it works fine in all browsers excerpt safari. Have got following errors in safari:

[image]

Would be glad if someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Already found a solution. I have changed all urls from http:// to https:// in the plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from OPs comment on their question:

> I have changed all urls from http:// to https:// in the plugin file.